# How do I modify 'subject' line of a TFS2010 build completion email alert?

Tags: tfsbuild

I'm trying to modify the alert email that is sent when a TFS team build completes.

I can modify the body of the mail via an edit to:  *BuildCompletionEvent.xsl*. However
[this 2006 post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/tfsadmin/thread/1a568a62-115a-4e46-8023-8db024767814/%20/) suggests the subject can't be changed, is this still the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't currently (tfs2010) change the subject of one of these alert emails.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can change the XSL email templates that are deployed with TFS 2008/2010/2012.  The folder structure is something like:

```
 "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Team Foundation Server\Web Services\Services\v1.0\Transforms"
```

After you modify it, you need to restart the application pool or the website because the templates are cached when the site starts.

Comment: thanks, I know where the transform (BuildCompletionEvent.xsl) lives, but isn't that for the body of the email only (and not the subject line)?

Comment: that's a great question and I don't know for sure :(